# ignore encoding error when parsing pdf with pdfminer

Tags: python, pdf

```
from pdfminer.pdfparser import PDFParser
from pdfminer.pdfdocument import PDFDocument
from pdfminer.pdftypes import resolve1
fn='test.pdf'
with open(fn, mode='rb') as fp:
    parser = PDFParser(fp)
    doc = PDFDocument(parser)
    fields = resolve1(doc.catalog['AcroForm'])['Fields']
    item = {}
    for i in fields:
        field = resolve1(i)
        name, value = field.get('T'), field.get('V')
        item[name]=value
```

Hello, I need help with this code as it is giving me Unicode error on some characters

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in <module>
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pdfminer/pdftypes.py", line 80, in resolve1
    x = x.resolve(default=default)
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pdfminer/pdftypes.py", line 67, in resolve
    return self.doc.getobj(self.objid)
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pdfminer/pdfdocument.py", line 673, in getobj
    stream = stream_value(self.getobj(strmid))
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pdfminer/pdfdocument.py", line 676, in getobj
    obj = self._getobj_parse(index, objid)
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pdfminer/pdfdocument.py", line 648, in _getobj_parse
    raise PDFSyntaxError('objid mismatch: %r=%r' % (objid1, objid))
  File "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pdfminer/psparser.py", line 85, in __repr__
    return self.name.decode('ascii')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe5 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

is there anything I can add so it "ingores" the charchters that its not able to decode or at least return the `name` with the value as blank in `name, value = field.get('T'), field.get('V')`.

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you can fix it

```
nano "/home/timmy/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pdfminer/psparser.py"
```

then in line 85

```
def __repr__(self):
    return self.name.decode('ascii', 'ignore') # this fixes it
```

I don't believe it's recommended to edit source scripts, you should also post an issue on Github